# TokenGuard (api) retrieving old user after second request

Tags: api, laravel, laravel-5

I'm testing my laravel (5.2) api the following way, by making two requests on the same test (routes on guard:api) :

```
$this->getJson('v1/ratings', 'POST');
// v1/ratingsapi_token=JcM6ftg6icLPGAbUX9E37HGSYsrAYU0GH1AJhoYxEfIi5LwhalRBf0iAcmJ2
```

Then i make the second request with a different token :

```
// v1/ratings?api_token=JgYdM890bIPHVYsiddHUp5vXaG9C1qhjLcYdZ1UioFZpPvPANGMqw26RJ3RB
```

But i'm still logged with the same user...

It comes from Illuminate\Auth\TokenGuard@user :

```
public function user()
    {
        // If we've already retrieved the user for the current request we can just
        // return it back immediately. We do not want to fetch the user data on
        // every call to this method because that would be tremendously slow.
        if (! is_null($this->user)) {
    // HERE IT GOES
            return $this->user;
        }
    ...
}
```

If i comment this block everything works fine, but i don't understand why it's getting the user from the previous request ?

Answer (score 0):

The current user is already cached in the property `$user`, so the TokenGuard won't send another request to retrieve the user, regardless of your different tokens and will return the old one.

As you can see the last line of the method sets the $user property to the retrieved user `return $this->user = $user;`.

Comment: I figured that, but it's not supposed to cache the user across 2 requests, as it's written in the description.

The good question would be : why the user persists on 2 different requests ?

Comment: Can you edit your post with how exactly you do your test? I mean is it PHPUnit, default Laravel test case, you enter the URLs in your browser or something else.

Comment: Actually just found why :
i'm never leaving the app while executing my 2 requests on my single test
So the TokenGuard is never rebuild, so it kept the old user.

Got to manually refresh your guard user while testing